# Call SAS macro in a loop

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a SAS macro ; And I have a dataset with one column and 100 observations.
How can I loop over these 100 observations and call the macro, each time passing the value of the n'th observation to the macro?

Comment: Look into call execute

Comment: Got it, thank you. I will close the question